# Probability of at least one pair

Tags: probability, solution-verification, combinations

I would like to ask, **if I am correctly formulating the solution** to Problem IV.1 from Feller's introduction to probability theory and application.

I'd appreciate any hints leading to the right approach.

> Ten pairs of shoes are in a closet. $4$ shoes are selected at random. Find the probability that there will be at least $1$ pair among the four shoes selected.

**My solution.**

My initial attempt was to define:

$A_{12}:=$ The event that the first two shoes are a pair.

$A_{34}:=$ The event that the last two shoes are a pair.

$A_{(12)(34)}:=$ The event that first two and last two are a pair.

$$P(A_{12}) = P(A_{34}) = \frac{{10 \choose 1}{18 \choose 2}}{{20 \choose 4}}$$

$$P(A_{(12)(34)}) = P(A_{34}) = \frac{{10 \choose 2}}{{20 \choose 4}}$$

So, using the expression for atleast one event:

$P_1 = S_1 - S_2 = 2\frac{{10 \choose 1}{18 \choose 2}}{{20 \choose 4}} - \frac{{10 \choose 2}}{{20 \choose 4}}=\frac{201}{323}$.

My choice of events looks plain stupid. The answer in Feller's book is $\frac{99}{323}$.

I think that the two quantities I have computed instead are the probabilities of the events:

$A_1 := \text{The event that 4 shoes have 1 pair}$

$A_2 := \text{The event that 4 shoes have 2 pairs}$

$P_1 = S_1 - S_2 = P(A_1) - P(A_2) = \frac{99}{323}$. This seems to work out correctly.

**Follow-on question.**

Why isn't the desired probability $P(A_1)$? Isn't it the the event, "one or more pairs"?

Comment: Not following.  Why couldn't the first and third shoes form a pair?

Comment: Nor can I follow your computation of $P(A_{12})$.  The first shoe can be anything, after which the second forms a pair with probability $\frac 1{19}$ which is much smaller than the answer you produced.

Comment: @lulu, I agree, that my initial attempt is entirely wrong. (First, third), (First, Fourth) anything could be a pair. Would it better to define $A_{1} := \text{One pair}$, $A_2:=\text{two pairs}$?

Comment: This sort of problem can best be handled from the compliment.  The probability that all $4$ are from different pairs is $1\times \frac {18}{19}\times \frac {16}{18}\times \frac {14}{17}=\frac {224}{323}$.

Comment: @lulu, I know how to do it using complementation. As chapter IV, is specifically about inclusion-exclusion, the expectation is to do it that way. Using complementation, one could also express it as $P(\text{atleast one pair}) = 1- P(\text{no pair})= 1 - \frac{{10 \choose 4}2^4}{{20 \choose 4}}=99/323$

Comment: Well, there are $\binom 42=6$ candidate pairs, of which at most two  (but not any two) can both be actual pairs.  I already showed you how to handle one specified pair, so the rest should be a little messy but entirely straight forward.

Comment: @lulu, do you mean to say: 

$${4 \choose 2}\frac{20 \times 1 \times 18 \times 16}{20 \times 19 \times 18 \times 17} + 3\frac{20 \times 1 \times 18 \times 1}{20 \times 19 \times 18 \times 17}$$

Comment: Well, first of all,  why would you add?  Inclusion Exclusion requires you to account for multiple counting by subtraction.

Comment: Nor can I follow your calculation for the first term.  I already showed you that the probability that two selected shoes is a pair is $\frac 1{19}$ so the first term should just be $\frac 6{19}$.

Comment: @lulu, the above is more like $P(\text{exactly 1 pair}) + P(\text{exactly 2 pairs})$.

Comment: No it isn't, and, besides, that's not how Inclusion Exclusion works.

Comment: Correction:  I thought you wanted to do it by Inclusion Exclusion.  If, instead, you wanted to isolate the cases in which there are exactly one pair and where there are exactly two pairs, then your method does work.  But, again, that's not Inclusion Exclusion.

Comment: @lulu, yeah what I wrote above is certainly not Inc-Exc. 

So, I figured: $P(\text{two selected shoes is a pair})=\frac{1}{19}$. There are $6$ such pairs $(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)$. $P(\text{four selected shoes have two pairs}) = (\frac{1}{19})(\frac{1}{17})$. There are $3$ such double pairs $((1,2),(3,4)),((1,3),(2,4)),(1,4),(2,3))$. 

$P(\text{atleast one pair})=\sum_{i}P(A_i)- \sum_{i<j}P(A_i A_j) = 6\frac{1}{19} -  3(\frac{1}{19})(\frac{1}{17})=\frac{99}{323}$.

Comment: Yes, that looks correct